# VB - DTSLib.DTSExecResult - compile error - Automation type not supported in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, ssis, compiler-errors

```
Dim pkg As DTSLib.Package
Dim pkgResult As DTSLib.DTSExecResult
```

This line (line:2) throws a compile error "Automation type not supported in visual basic" 
I'm trying to use pkgResult to capture the results of running a dtsx on server

```
Set pkg = app.LoadFromDtsServer("\MSDB\", Server, True, pevents)
pkgResults = pkg.Execute()
```

Please note: I have added a reference to  "Microsoft DTS Runtime 1.0"

Doesnt VB support type DTSLib.DTSExecResult ??

Appreciate your help and time. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use the legacy DTS (SQL Server 2000) or DTSX (2005+). They are very different creatures and require different references.

Comment: I'm using DTSX. But this is a compilation error in VB code ..for DTSLib.DTSExecResult, could this be related to the sql server version?